# std::exchange binds an lvalue to rvalue reference as second parameter

Tags: c++

As per this link https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/exchange `std::exchange` takes an `rvalue reference` as second parameter, that means it cannot bind to a `lvalue` argument if passed. But the example given in the link compiles without any error. Am I missing something here? Can somebody explain this concept.

Comment: That's not an rvalue reference. It's a universal reference, which can bind to both rvalues and lvalues.

Comment: See __Forwarding references__ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference (Universal / Forwarding - there was a name change - not sure which is current).